# Integral with closed form? $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n\ln x}{(1+x)^2(1+x^m)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate
$$I(n,m)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n\ln x}{(1+x)^2(1+x^m)}dx$$
and I'm strongly convinced that it has a nice closed form. This is because if you plug small values for $(n,m)$, you get neat results in terms of $\pi^2$. Here are some examples:
$$I(0,2)=-\frac{\pi^2}{16}$$
$$I(0,3)=-\frac16-\frac{4\pi^2}{81}$$
$$I(0,4)=\frac{2\sqrt2-5}{32}\pi^2$$
$$I(1,3)=\frac16-\frac{2\pi^2}{81}$$
$$I(3,4)=\frac{4\sqrt2-5}{64}\pi^2$$
I managed to calculate some of them via partial fractions. The others are from WolframAlpha.

**Two interesting facts**:

**1)** Notice that $$I(n,m)=-I(m-n,m)$$ This is easily obtained by letting $x=\frac1t$ in the integral. It follows that, for example:
$$I(2,3)=\frac{2\pi^2}{81}-\frac16$$
$$I(1,4)=\frac{5-4\sqrt2}{64}\pi^2$$

**2)** From the same result follows also that $I(n,2n)=0$, and so we get beautiful results like
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}\log x}{(1+x)^3}dx=0$$

I am clueless on how to solve the general case. I think it's useful to reduce it to
$$I(n,m)=\int_0^1\frac{x^n\log x}{(1+x)^2(1+x^m)}dx-\int_0^1\frac{x^{m-n}\log x}{(1+x)^2(1+x^m)}dx$$
Expanding $\frac{1}{1+t^m}$ in series reduces the problem to evaluating integrals of the form
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^a\log x}{(1+x)^2}dx$$
and then summing the result over $\mathbb N$
, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming m is a positive integer value greater than 1, we can always break down a fraction of the form $\frac{1}{1+x^m}$ as follows using partial fraction decomposition.
$$\frac{1}{1+x^m}=\frac{1}{(x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_m)}=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{C_k}{x-r_k}$$
This reduces the problem into
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n\ln x}{(1+x)^2(1+x^m)}dx=\sum_{k=1}^mC_k\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n\ln x}{(1+x)^2(x-r_k)}dx$$
Now we evaluate the integral by splitting it at x=1
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n\ln x}{(1+x)^2(x-r_k)}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\ln x}{(1+x)^2(x-r_k)}dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{x^n\ln x}{(1+x)^2(x-r_k)}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\ln x}{(1+x)^2(x-r_k)}dx+\int_0^1 \frac{x^{3-n}\ln x}{(1+x)^2(1-r_kx)}dx=I(n,r_k)-\frac{1}{r_k}I(3-n,\frac{1}{r_k})$$
We can calculate $I(n,r_k)$ by using a series expansion, integrating term by term, and using the Lerch transcendent function.
$$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2(x-r)}=\frac{1}{(r+1)^2}\frac{1}{x-r}-\frac{1}{(r+1)^2}\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{r+1)}\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$$$=-\frac{1}{r(r+1)^2}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)^l-\frac{1}{(r+1)^2}\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-x)^l-\frac{1}{r+1}\sum_{l=0}^\infty(l+1)(-x)^l$$
$$I(n,r_k)=\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln x}{(1+x)^2(x-r_k)}dx$$$$=-\frac{1}{r(r+1)^2}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{x^{l+n}\ln x}{r^l}dx-\frac{1}{(r+1)^2}\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-1)^l\int_0^1x^{l+n}\ln x\space  dx-\frac{1}{r+1}\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-1)^l(l+1)\int_0^1x^{l+n}\ln x\space dx$$$$=\frac{1}{r(r+1)^2}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{1}{r^l(l+n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(r+1)^2}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^l}{(l+n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{r+1}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^l}{l+n+1}-\frac{n}{r+1}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^l}{(l+n+1)^2}$$$$=\frac{1}{r(r+1)^2}\Phi(1/r,2,n+1)+\frac{1-n(r+1)}{(r+1)^2}\Phi(-1,2,n+1)+\frac{1}{r+1}\Phi(-1,1,n+1)$$
Now that we have calculated $I(n,r_k)$, we can plug it back in.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n\ln x}{(1+x)^2(x-r_k)}dx=I(n,r_k)-\frac{1}{r_k}I(3-n,\frac{1}{r_k})$$
$$=\frac{1}{r_k(r_k+1)^2}\Phi(1/r_k,2,n+1)+\frac{1-n(r_k+1)}{(r_k+1)^2}\Phi(-1,2,n+1)+\frac{1}{r_k+1}\Phi(-1,1,n+1)-\frac{r_k^2}{(r_k+1)^2}\Phi(r_k,2,4-n)-\frac{r_k-(3-n)(r_k+1)}{(r_k+1)^2}\Phi(-1,2,4-n)-\frac{1}{r_k+1}\Phi(-1,1,4-n)$$
Now we can give the original integral as a finite sum of Lerch transcendents by summing over k to m, coming out to a total of $6m$ Lerch transcendents
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n \ln x}{(1+x)^2(1+x^m)}=-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{r_k}{m}\left(I(n,r_k)-\frac{1}{r_k}I(3-n,\frac{1}{r_k})\right)$$
Where $r_1,r_2,...,r_m$ are roots of the equation $x^m+1=0$

Remember that using the ['cover up' method](https://brilliant.org/wiki/partial-fractions-cover-up-rule/) for partial fractions, we can find $C_k$ for this case
$$C_k=\lim_{x\rightarrow r_k}\frac{x-r_k}{1+x^m}=\frac{1}{mr_k^{m-1}}=-\frac{r_k}{m}$$

Comment: In $I(n,r)$, the second and third Lerch transcendent may be simplified into polygamma functions

Comment: Quite interesting that, even with most of the $r_k$ complex, the result ends up being real

Answer (score 6):

> and now expanding $\frac{1}{1+t^m}$ in series reduces the problem to evaluating integrals of the form
> $$\int_0^1\frac{x^a\log x}{(1+x)^2}dx$$
> but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Let $$J=\int_0^1\frac{x^a}{(1+x)^2} dx$$

Integration by part,
$$J=-\frac{1}2+a\int_0^1\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x} dx=-\frac{1}2+a\sum_{n=0}(-1)^n\int_0^1 x^{n+a-1} dx=-\frac{1}2+a\sum_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+a}$$

we have
$$I=\frac{dJ}{da}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{{x}^{a}\ln x}{(1+x)^2} dx=\sum_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+a}-a\sum_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+a)^2}$$

**Remarks:**

We can generalize the OP into this form
$$I(n,m, k)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n\ln^k x}{(1+x)^2(1+x^m)}dx$$

Let:
$$H=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{(1+x)^2(1+x^m)}dx$$

hence
$$I(n,m, k)=\frac{d^k H }{da^k}\bigg|_{a=n}$$

To compute $H$, we can use contour integral, with the classic key-hole contour, with the branch cut along positive x-axis. The integral vanishes on the large circle when $a<m+1$, and the integral vanishes on the small circle when $-1<a$, therefore, we require $-1<a<m+1$

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{z^a}{(1+z)^2(1+z^m)}dz-\int_0^\infty\frac{z^ae^{2\pi a i}}{(1+z)^2(1+z^m)}dz=2\pi i \sum_p Res(z_p)$$
so we get

$$H=\int_0^\infty\frac{z^a}{(1+z)^2(1+z^m)}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{1-e^{2\pi a i}} \sum_p Res(z_p)$$

When computing the residues, there are two cases,

(1). if $m$ is odd,

$z_p=-1$ is a 3rd order pole. $z_p=e^{\frac{2p+1}{m}\pi i}, p=0,1,\dots,\frac{m-3}2,\frac{m+1}2,\dots,m-1$ are simple poles.

(2). if $m$ is even,

$z_p=-1$ is a 2rd order pole. $z_p=e^{\frac{2p+1}{m}\pi i}, p=0,1,\dots,m-1$ are simple poles.

Comment: Because this is to answer your question on how to proceed to evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{x^a\log x}{(1+x)^2}dx$. @Zima